# heading and value in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to implement this layout : (* my question is about the section which surrounded with red color* ).

[image]

I've implemented it  as :

The overall markup(simplified) :

```
<div class=" row">
    <div>Your Personal Information</div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class=".col-lg-4 ">
          ...left side...
       </div>
       <div class=".col-lg-8">
          ...right side...
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

[**Here is what I've tried :**](http://jsbin.com/tovajifi/4/edit) 
[image]

**2 questions :**

**1)** What is the right way ( using bootstrap 3) to do the **left** pane rows ? 
    should each line  has to be with `.row`? Also , what is the right way to show : `header`:`value` ?

**2)** why does the `bla bla` row - is not on the right side ? I did use `.col-lg-4` and `.col-lg-8` as the docs state that I should use.

## edit

I just noticed that the classes were with `.`  , removed those dots , and used `col-xs-4/8` instead and now it's working. but still - what is the right way of writing :  ( which classes should I use)

```
"header1":"value1"
"header2":"value2"
```

updated jsbin : http://jsbin.com/tovajifi/6/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the classes used and the width of the browser window:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
    Left column here
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-8">
    Right Columnt here
</div>
```

Basically if you use the `col-lg-8` class on a small screen (let's say a phone) it won't work because that class only works on large screens.

About the `"header":"value"` problem the simplest way is just:

```
<p>Country of Origin: <strong>Israel</strong><p>
```

Here it's the whole snippet: http://jsbin.com/tovajifi/7/

More informations can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type

Comment: Can u please see my edit and answer the part about `"header1":"value1"` ?should it be `<div>header1</div> : <div> value1 </div>` or with span and in which classes ?

Comment: in short how do i implement the red circle . ( the actuall lines!) Ill be very thankful if you could edit the jsbin, I used div as a seperator which is very bad I think. what are the BS classes for this case ?

Comment: Tnx. p.s. isnt there any general case instead of writing all those  `col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-8` ?

Comment: Not one that i'm aware of. Give a look here by the way: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid